# Sidr.js equivalent for AngularJS without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sidr

Is there any equivalent for [Sidr.js](https://www.berriart.com/sidr/) without jQuery to use in an Angular Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this and I think it is very useful to share here. I implemented slideout.js to replace Sidr.js. Thanks. https://mango.github.io/slideout/